# Column Filtering in Datatables using Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, datatables, angular7

I am trying to implement Datatables in my angular project where the data fetched from WebAPI is rendered and displayed in the datatables.

I would like to implement Column Filtering. I went through this link to learn but here the code is written in Javascript [Column Filter](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html)
. Is there any way that I can inject the above code in my angular project? I am new to angular so can't figure out where to add the code.

Here's the function which starts my Datatables

```
loadProjects(){
this.projectService.getProject().subscribe(
    productData => {
      this.projects = productData;
      this.dataTable = $(this.Table.nativeElement);
      setTimeout(()=>{this.dataTable.DataTable();}, 50);
    }
);
```

}

I went through [this article](https://medium.com/ramsatt/integrate-datatable-with-angular-6-application-part-4-hidden-columns-90b81dc37d46) but it only shows how to enable or disable feature. How can I add the functions of datatable in my angular 7 project?

How to inject this piece of code in my Angular Project?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );
$('#example thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

    $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
            table
                .column(i)
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    orderCellsTop: true,
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```

} );

Comment: do you have pagination in your webapi? typescript can use javascript too.try to imort this (type definition)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/datatables.net] first.

Comment: I would suggest use https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort table

Comment: Yes pagination is enabled. I know how to enable or disable the features but can't exactly figure out where and how to add the functions given in the datatable api?